# How does mean parameter in rnorm function works?

Tags: r

I am curious about how exactly does the mean parameter in rnorm function work?
Because, when I pass `rnorm(n = 2, mean = 2)`, it does fetch me two random numbers (which is understood) but, not sure about the significance of mean value that we are passing as the second parameter. The output is 2 random numbers but, the mean is never 2.

Comment: Try `mean(rnorm(n=1e7, mean=2))`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  That parameter is the center of the distribution that is being sample from.  With only two values the sample mean is unlikely to be the population mean but if you increase the sample size the observed mean will get closer to the parameter value.  In other words, the sample mean will approximate the expected value.

Comment: It gives you random numbers following a normal distribution. A Normal distribution is defined by its mean and its standard deviation. By definition, 99.73% of the values will be between [mean-3sd;mean+3sd], 64% between [mean-sd;mean+sd]. By default, rnorm has mean=0, and sd=1, so it generates numbers between [-3;+3] 99.73% of the time. If you turn mean=2, you create a normal law with mean=2, and sd stays=1. But of course, if you pick only two numbers, the sample mean won't be exactly the one of the distribution. It will become closer to the mean of the normal law when you increase n.

Comment: As mentioned, `rnorm` outputs random variables given parameter inputs (according to a normal distribution). This Cross Validated answer may help your understanding of probability distributions: [What is the difference between parameter and variable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255983/what-is-the-difference-between-parameter-and-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Argument `2` tells `rnorm` to sample the list from a normal distribution with a mean `2`. It does not ensure that the mean will be exactly 2 in a specific run.